# "AlreadyBuiltException: This object has already been built" when building "springSecurityFilterChain"

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm developing a Spring Boot application with Spring Security, and could not get it working in any way.

I want to use Spring Security 5, but at this point I don't even know what version I am trying to use, and using WebFlux will not help.

The problem is that when I create a class that extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, Spring will always throw `org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AlreadyBuiltException: This object has already been built` after `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AlreadyBuiltException: This object has already been built`, and I don't know why. I tried removing the `@Configuration` annotation, the `@EnableWebSecurity` one, both and adding others, such as `@Order`, but adding or removing annotations don't seem help.

Here is the stack trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AlreadyBuiltException: This object has already been built
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1305) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1144) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:307) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:849) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at net.digib.LibraryManager.main(LibraryManager.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AlreadyBuiltException: This object has already been built
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AlreadyBuiltException: This object has already been built
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:44) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity.performBuild(WebSecurity.java:294) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity.performBuild(WebSecurity.java:79) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:334) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:104) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$46929e0c.CGLIB$springSecurityFilterChain$5(<generated>) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$46929e0c$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7515a245.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$46929e0c.springSecurityFilterChain(<generated>) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

And my WebSecurityConfig class, that extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    public static final String ROLE_COMUM = "COMUM";
    public static final String ROLE_ULTRA = "ULTRA";

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/*/inserir").hasAuthority(ROLE_ULTRA)
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().formLogin()
                .and().build();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
                .withUser("usuario").password(passwordEncoder().encode("senha")).roles(ROLE_COMUM)
                .and()
                .withUser("ultra").password(passwordEncoder().encode("ahnes")).roles(ROLE_COMUM, ROLE_ULTRA);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

How can I prevent Spring from creating multiple `springSecurityFilterChain`, so that my application can run correctly?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
Caused by: org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AlreadyBuiltException: This object has already been built
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:44) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity.performBuild(WebSecurity.java:294) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity.performBuild(WebSecurity.java:79) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:334) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
```

It happens when `HttpSecurity#build()` is called more than one time per instance. You don't need to call `HttpSecurity#build()` when configuring `HttpSecurity` as spring security will call it behind scenes. So removing `build()` in `configure(HttpSecurity http)` should solve the problem :

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/*/inserir").hasAuthority(ROLE_ULTRA)
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().formLogin();
}
```

Comment: I had a facepalm right now, how could I not spot that? But, thanks anyway. I was having trouble with this problem for some days.

Comment: I had the same problem, called `#build()` multiple times. I was doing `http.whatEverConfig().build()` and theeen ... `return http.build()`.